# Angular 11 app is not responsive it freezes in IOS 15.5 version but works fine in 15.4 version

Tags: ios, angular, angular11

Below is the package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/architect": "0.1102.4",
"@angular/animations": "11.2.5",
"@angular/cdk": "^11.2.5",
"@angular/common": "11.2.5",
"@angular/compiler": "11.2.5",
"@angular/core": "11.2.5",
"@angular/forms": "11.2.5",
"@angular/material": "^11.2.13",
"@angular/platform-browser": "11.2.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.2.5",
"@angular/router": "11.2.5",
"@azure/msal-angular": "^2.0.3",
"@azure/msal-browser": "^2.17.0",
"@types/googlemaps": "3.26.17",
"angularx-qrcode": "^11.0.0",
"bootstrap": "3.3.7",
"core-js": "2.4.1",
"font-awesome": "4.7.0",
"intl": "1.2.5",
"moment-timezone": "0.5.13",
"ngx-device-detector": "^2.0.3",
"ngx-mask": "8.0.1",
"ngx-material-timepicker": "^4.0.2",
"ngx-toastr": "^13.2.1",
"primeicons": "^4.0.0-rc.2",
"primeng": "^9.1.3",
"rxjs": "6.6.6",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.6.6",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
"xml2js": "0.4.19",
"zone.js": "^0.11.0"
 },

"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.4",
   "@angular-devkit/schematics": "11.2.4",
   "@angular/cli": "11.2.4",
   "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.2.5",
   "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
   "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
   "@types/lodash": "4.14.118",
   "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
   "browser-sync": "^2.26.14",
   "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
   "http-server": "13.0.1",
   "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
   "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
   "karma": "~6.2.0",
   "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
   "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
   "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
   "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
   "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
   "lodash": "4.17.11",
   "protractor": "~7.0.0",
   "ts-node": "^8.3.0",
   "tslint": "~6.1.0",
  "typescript": "4.0.7"
   }
```

we closed all type of subscriptions/added for loop breaks added and same code works fine on previous version iOS 15.4. Can anyone please suggest me what could be the issue or in which direction to debug exactly.
we are using angular 11 version as ios got updated 15.5 version upgrade the app freezes after an hour or 2 and does not respond anymore

Comment: Connect the iOS device to a mac and debug it from Safari. Search the web for instructions how to do it.

Comment: @added and checked but no use it still behaves as mac not as iOS device